# MVC: Cannot view my error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have setup ELMAH in my MVC application and I want to display a friendly scren if an exception is thrown.
However I still get the YSOD.
So in my web.config I have 

      
    
(I have also tried the other modes with no success).
My error controller has 
namespace ITOF.Controllers
{
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult Unknown()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View("Unknown");
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult NotFound(string path)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View("NotFound", path);
    }
}
```

}

These methods get called when the mode="On"

However I then get a Runtime Error YSOD which tells me to change my web.config customError mode="RemoteOnly"

Maybe there is an error in my Views?

Here they are;

Unknown.cshtml;

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
```

NotFound.cshtml;

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Not Found";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Lost?</h2>

    <p>Sorry - your request doesn't exist or was deleted.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `NotFound` action you should be returning:

```
return View("NotFound", (object)path);
```

Notice how I am casting the second parameter to object in order to use the correct overload of the method. Otherwise you are calling the overload where the second argument represents a masterpage name.